# Porting iOS app on Blackberry 10

Tags: ios, xcode, blackberry-10, blackberry-cascades

I want to port the iOS app (ex.HelloWorld) developed in XCode on Blackberry 10 device.
I have gone through the [Cascades for Blackberry 10](http://developer.blackberry.com/cascades/documentation/getting_started/), but according to this, needs to install an [Blackberry Native SDK and QNX Momentics IDE](http://developer.blackberry.com/native/download/).

Is there any other option or possibility for doing this through XCode.

I know that, If I developed it in **QNX Momentics IDE**, then it will work, but my question is that is it possible using **XCode**.

Comment: Well, are you sure this is dependent of the IDE? I have a feeling this is rather a question specific to the different architectures and toolchains used.

Comment: According to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14648231/porting-android-app-to-run-on-blackberry-10-android-runtime-google-maps android app can run on Blackberry 10.

Comment: that's not what I'm talking about. (And of course it can, they both run Linux, essentially. iOS is not linux [what a shame], so it won't be an easy path for sure.)

Comment: Xcode is the IDE used to develop apple products(iOS/Mac) not for Blackberry

Comment: @H2CO3 I know that iOS is not linux. But Blackerry-10 uses C/C++. Why shame & downvote as well? I already know it hard but just want to know the possibility.

Comment: @Girish Again, it's not the language either. iOS runs on C as well. But practically, it would be possible for any language (respecting the ABI and C calling conventions of the platform) to interact with already existing code. The problem is the presence or absence of system libraries.

Comment: @H2CO3: BlackberryOS is based on the QNX microkernel  - so, no, it doesn't run linux. QNX is POSIX compatible though (as is iOS for that matter).  However, compatibility at this level is irrelevant for mobile phone apps.

Comment: @Marko Thanks for the info (yes, I should have googled it or STFU... :( ) - but what do you mean by "compatibility at this level is irrelevant for mobile phone apps"? It surely isn't. It decides whether or not an application can run on a particular OS/architecture.

Comment: @H2CO3 Because almost nothing you build on any of these platforms ever uses low level APIs such as POSIX directly.  Te higher level APIs are not compatible.

Comment: @Marko Hum. OP wrote that it's possible to program BB using C and C++. That holds (simplified) to iOS too. Now what?

Comment: @H2CO3 any practical hello world app on a smartphone that has no console requires use of a non-portable UI library to do its business.

Comment: @Marko means I needs to create an app on QNX Momentics IDE. correct?

Comment: @Marko Yes, that's what I'm talking about. That's why compatibility matters. These libraries can be written in a number of languages, but if they are written in one of the C-type natively compiled languages (C, C++, Objective-C), then ABI compatibility is a strong concern.

Comment: @Girish None of them are ABI compatible with each other, even at the library level.  For a start, ARM register usage is slightly different in iOS and Mach-o objects are used.  You will need to recompile for each platform, but this is at least possible for clean standards compliant C or C++.

Answer (score 1):

If you want do develop with the cascades framework, there is nothing on xCode from Blackberry. The community just allow Qt Creator to develop for Cascades. As it is the main IDE for Qt, there is no chance at all that another project on xCode could have done it also in the same time.
But anyway, you'll lose QML editor, Memory tracker, easy integration with Cascades libraries, ... Use the tools adapted to the situation.

If you develop for native only, then it may be possible to develop on xCode and build with the commandLine.
Did you had look here ? https://developer.blackberry.com/native/documentation/bb10/porting_ios_intro.html